# how to stop the page from continuously loading

Tags: php

I have the following code that is meant to delete the user if their antispam date has expired. Everything seems to be working but the only problem that I am having lately is that the page just keeps loading over and over again as if the `exit()` is not working.... It was working before but am not sure if I did change the code or anything but it seems to be looping through...

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  include_once __DIR__.'/header2.php';
  if ($_SESSION['u_uid']) {
     echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=header2.php?index=mustloggedoutfirst'>"; 
     exit();
  } else {
    include_once __DIR__.'/includes/dbh.php';
    $date = strip_tags(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $activate = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE banned = ? AND ? < antispam";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
       echo 'SQL error';
       exit();
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "is", $banned, $date);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $username = $row['user_uid'];
        $email = $row['user_email'];
        $first_name = $row['user_first'];
        $last_name = $row['user_last'];

        if($resultCheck > 0) {           
          echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php?signup=banned'>"; 
          exit();
        } else {            
          $sql2 = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_uid = ? AND user_email = ?;";
          $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
          if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
            echo "SQL error";
          } else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $email);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            $sql3 = "DELETE FROM memberships WHERE user_uid = ? AND user_email = ?;";

            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql3)) {
              echo "SQL error";
            } else {
              mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $email);
              mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

              $sql4 = "DELETE FROM customer_lessonfees WHERE user_uid = ? AND user_email = ?;";

              $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
              if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql4)) {
                echo "SQL error";
              } else {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $email);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                $sql5 = "DELETE FROM rewards WHERE user_uid = ? AND user_email = ?;";

                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql5)) {
                  echo "SQL error";
                } else {
                  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $email);
                  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                  $sql6 = "DELETE FROM student_details WHERE user_uid = ? AND user_email = ?;";

                  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                  if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql6)) {
                    echo "SQL error";
                  } else {
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $email);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                    // Edit this path if PHPMailer is in a different location.

                    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
                    include_once __DIR__.'/PHPMailer/Exception.php';
                    include_once __DIR__.'/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
                    include_once __DIR__.'/PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
                    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
                    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
                    //$mail->isSMTP();  enable this for localhost and disable for live host??? 
                    $mail->isHTML(true);

                    /*
                     * Server Configuration
                     */

                    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // Which SMTP server to use.
                    $mail->Port = 587; // Which port to use, 587 is the default port for TLS and 465 for SSL security.
                    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Which security method to use. TLS is most secure.
                    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Whether you need to login. This is almost always required.
                    $mail->Username = "pianocourseforkids101@gmail.com"; // Your Gmail address.
                    $mail->Password = "*******"; // Your Gmail login password or App Specific Password.

                    /*
                     * Message Configuration
                     */

                    $mail->setFrom('Admin@pianocourse101.com', 'PianoCourse101 Account Deleted'); // Set the sender of the message.
                    $mail->addAddress($email, 'PianoCourse101 Account Deleted'); // Set the recipient of the message.
                    $mail->Subject = 'PianoCourse101 Account Deleted'; // The subject of the message.

                    /*
                     * Message Content - Choose simple text or HTML email
                     */

                    // Choose to send either a simple text email...
                    $mail->Body = "Dear $first_name $last_name <br /></br />

                    You have received this e-mail because your Primer Level Account has been deleted!<br /><br />You have not completed your anti-spam question within 24 hours and must now re-register if you would still like to use your Primer Level Account.

                    <br /><br />

                    From,

                    <br /><br />

                    PianoCourse101
                    "; // Set a plain text body.

                    // ... or send an email with HTML.
                    //$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'));
                    // Optional when using HTML: Set an alternative plain text message for email clients who prefer that.
                    //$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body'; 

                    // Optional: attach a file
                    $mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');
                    if ($mail->send()) {
                      echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php?delete_request=success'>";
                      exit();        
                    } else {
                      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                    }        
                    ob_end_flush();
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
 ?>
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that if I got rid of the echo and exit lines, then it will stop loading but i thought you would need to add those redirect

Comment: I guess maybe my problem is that I am sending a redirect to the same page

Comment: but I am still wondering why the message is still showing even without the echo

Comment: I just thought that you would need the echo to display an error message

Comment: is this page `index.php`?

Comment: if yes try redirecting to a different page with success or error message, dont load the same page.

Comment: it is the index.php page but for some reason, the error message is still showing even without the echo

Comment: I think my logic is that I have done the code in the wrong file... it should be done in the login.php